# Databases in SQL Management Studio not available in server A, but in server B with the same user I can see all databases

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection

After domain migration I am not able to see the databases in SQL management studio from a Windows 2016 server.

With the same user on a terminal or the SQL server I am able to see all the databaes in SSMS.

Now I am getting stuck with Exact, I can find the server but not the databases from that specific server. On a Terminal server with the same user I am able to login to the database from Exact and SSMS.

I am able to see the databases when I use odbcad.exe and connect with one of the databases.

The user is sysadmin in SQL.

What did I forgot to do?

I tried to use the cliconf.exe with protocols, nothing worked for this situation.

Comment: So you saying the databases are not enumerated when using the Exact application but are visible via all other tools using the same account? In that case, this looks to be a problem with the Exact configuration. You could try to troubleshoot on your own with a trace of the Exact queries or contact the vendor.

Comment: Not correctly, only from one server (2008 server) are the databases visible in Exact. From the Windows 2016 server they are not. Not in Exact and not from SQL Server management studio. 

When we log on to the SQL server with the same user, we open SQL Server magement studio, we see all the databases.

Comment: Does the database server have the domain migration or your account? Can you use a SQL Server account to see the databases?